# Showing if $H,K$ are subgroups of $G$, the $\varphi(hak)=a^{-1}hak$ is bijective.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, self-learning

Here's my problem...I have to ultimately show that $\varphi(hak)=\varphi(hbk)\Rightarrow hak=hbk$ and I'm having issues...
I am told, both $H,K$ are subgroups of $G$ and $a\in G$.  The goal is to show if $\varphi:HaK\rightarrow a^{-1}HaK, \varphi(hak)=a^{-1}hak$ is a bijective map.  so I start with the one-to-one argument...
$$\varphi(hak)=\varphi(hbk)$$
$$a^{-1}hak=b^{-1}hbk$$
$$hak=ab^{-1}hbk$$
And I'm stuck...what can i do to remedy this?

Also, is the surjective argument simply shown by the way the two sets are defined as $HaK$ and $a^{-1}HaK$?  Or do we have to say let $a\in a^{-1}HaK$...then 
$$a=a^{-1}ah^{-1}hak^{-1}k$$
and deduce from that or something like that?

Comment: The question and the notation are unclear. You should mention *all* the hypotheses and the *whole* context.

Comment: Where does the $b$ come from? You want to show that $\phi$ is bijective. For injectivity, start with two elements of $HaK$, say $hak$ and $h'ak'$ and keep going.

Comment: For surjectivity, start with an arbitrary element of $a^{-1}HaK$, say $a^{-1} h a k$ and show that it is in the image of $\phi$. This is trivial, as it's the image of $h a k$.

Comment: i should have said $b\in G$?  And now I see where the error is...thanks

Comment: No, you shouldn't have taken any $b$ at all.

Comment: I meant that now I see that there was no b mentioned, I just needed to consider $h'$ and $k'$

Comment: Thanks for the downvote...just trying to figure out where my errors are...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This doesn't depend on $H$ and $K$ being subgroups at all. If you take an arbitrary subset $X$ of $G$ and $a \in G$, then the map $X \to a^{-1} X$ defined by $x \mapsto a^{-1} x$ is a bijection. The inverse is, of course, given by $y \mapsto a y$.